# How to delete GPS metadata only if it's match a coordinate using ExifTool?

Tags: gps, metadata, exiftool

I want to delete all GPS information of my photos only if it match a specific GPS coordinate.

I have read the man page but I'm not sure that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match an exact coordinate, something like this (windows version):
`exiftool -if "$GPSLongitude eq '‎74 deg 2\' 40.20\" W'  and $GPSLatitude eq '40 deg 41\' 21.28\" N'" -gps*= FileOrDir`

or if you're using numeric coordinates
`exiftool -if "$GPSLongitude# == -74.0445  and $GPSLatitude# == 40.6892444444444" -gps*= FileOrDir`

I used `-gps*=` to clear out all tags that start with `gps` because it's possible that there could be a lot more tags as well as XMP gps tags.  If you want to just clear out position data while leaving GPS direction/speed/timestamp/destination/etc data, then you could use `-GPSLatitude= -GPSLongitude= -GPSLatitudeRef= -GPSLongitudeRef=` instead (maybe `-GPSAltitude= -GPSAltitudeRef=` as well).

For the first command in Windows, you'll have to escape the single and double quotes that are inside the single quoted part of the equation with backslashes.  I'm not sure how it would be done on Mac/Linux.

The one main problem would be the degree of accuracy.  If you have a number is close, but not exactly equal to the gps local stored in the file, you won't get a match.  At that point, you may want to look into the [`-c`](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#c-FMT--coordFormat) option where you can specify the degree of precision.
`exiftool -if "$GPSLongitude == -74.0445 and $GPSLatitude == 40.689244" -c "%+.6f" -gps*= FileOrDir`

Finally, if you want to get more complex, you can put just about any perl expression as the argument for the `-if` option.  For example, you could subtract your number from the `$GPSLatitude` and get the absolute value to get a range to compare.  [Example](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=7491.0) from the Exiftool forums:
`exiftool -if 'abs($gpslatitude# -  52.3728268506806) < 1e-3 and abs($gpslongitude# - 4.89373108651944) < 1e-3'`

Comment: With your command I can't make the script match the files. It always says X files failed the condition. From where I should get the numbers? From google maps? Using the proprieties window from Windows ?  Can you expand a little bit on -c switch ? I couldn't find info about it on google. http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html This website says -c does something different.

Comment: As I said, the problem is the degree of accuracy.  It's hard to match the exact number in the file unless you know the exact coordinate and the degree of precision.  Then it also depends upon what format the coordinate you're looking for is in.  That's where the `-c` option comes in.  It allows you to specify the format so that it can match the format your coordinate is in.  The example I gave `-c "%+.6f" gave six decimal places of precision, which is down to centimeters level of accuracy.  Far to precise, IMO.  What is the exact command you tried and what format are your coords in?

Comment: My suggestion is to use the last command, if possible.  That command uses 1e-3 (or 0.001) which on the coordinate scale is a radius of about a football field.  To tighten it up further, use 0.0001 which would be about 30' radius.  That way you don't have to get the exact same coordinate, you can be close enough and still remove the gps data.

Comment: Can we talk in chat or other way? I have a few quick questions that I feel could become repetitive or spammy here in the comments.

Comment: Certainly.  Head over to the [Exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php) and link back to this thread. There's lots of help there.

Comment: Hmmm… I'm not really eager to put my email out there and this site doesn't have a PM system.  I can be reached on the Exiftool forums, of course, or on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/StarGeekSpaceNerd).  Or if you have another suggestion, I'm open to that.